# Can we change the text/background color of an individual property in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, propertygrid

I have a .NET PropertyGrid control which displays properties of some class.  I want to change the color or font or background color(it doesn't matter just that they look different from the other displayed properties) of some property. I can do with writing custom editor but I was wondering:

1. If an easier method exists?
2. If I use custom editor then how do i change the editor of built-in types like bool, int etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No can do.  The class that determines how an item is drawn is PropertyGridView.  The source code is interesting, it almost made it:

```
    private /*protected virtual*/ PropertyGridView CreateGridView(IServiceProvider sp) {
        return new PropertyGridView(sp, this);
    }
```

Nope, looks like at the last minute they decided against making the method overridable.  The PropertyGridView class was also marked internal.  Replacing all this code (there is a *lot* of it) is not a realistic option.

Creating your own UITypeEditor for built-in types is only possible by applying the [Editor] attribute to the properties in the class you want to edit.  That's not a general solution.  Consider creating your own form to make the object editable instead.

Comment: Is there a way to change the property name instead. I would like to add "*" before the name to indicate the difference for example "*Font" instead of "Font". I tried with reflection but displayName field is shown in the debugger which when change works however I am unable to get the field from  reflection.
I am using proper binding flags ie BindingFlags.NonPublic

Comment: Not sure whether I do understand the very first sentence "No can do." correctly. Being a non-native English speaker, I would have thought, that it should read "No can't do.". Am I missing something?