# Winforms PropertyGrid Style

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I want to use property grid to show differences between objects. Everything is fine but how I can highlight (change back or fore color) for properties which have differences? 
Is it possible?

Maybe someone suggest alternatives of this control to have nice visualization of object differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During searching across different articles I fond that it's not possible in clear way
Nice explanation of why pointed by @Hans Passant
[Can we change the text/background color of an individual property in PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857606/can-we-change-the-text-background-color-of-an-individual-property-in-propertygri)

Also it has nice but not free alternative from VisualHint company 
[Smart PropertyGrid.Net](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/A4A710C1-7B90-4C36-A4FA-FF12B99B54C6)

But it my case it's possible to hack existing functionality little bit as I need just one color for visualization of differences in properties. What I did is just used property DisabledItemForeColor which defining color for ReadOnly properties, and made mapping of ReadOnly property to custom property HasDifference.

So here is my sample code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        var obj = new CustomObjectType
        {
            ObjectName = "CompositeFirst",
            Properties =
            {
                new CustomProperty { Name = "Property1", Type = typeof(int), Desc = "Property1 desc", DefaultValue = 1, HasDifference = true},
                new CustomProperty { Name = "Property2", Type = typeof(DateTime), Desc = "Property2 desc"},
                new CustomProperty { Name = "Property1", Type = typeof(CustomObjectType), HasDifference = true},
            }
        };

        var customObjectType = obj.Properties[2].DefaultValue as CustomObjectType;
        if (customObjectType != null)
            customObjectType.ObjectName = "CompositSecond";
            customObjectType.Properties = new List<CustomProperty>
            {
                new CustomProperty { Name = "Property4", Type = typeof(int), DefaultValue = 5, HasDifference = true},
                new CustomProperty { Name = "Property5", Type = typeof(DateTime), Desc = "Property2 desc", DefaultValue = DateTime.Now},
            };

        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = obj;    
        propertyGrid1.DisabledItemForeColor = Color.Red;
    }


    [TypeConverter(typeof(CustomObjectConverter))]
    public class CustomObjectType : TypeConverter 
    {
        private List<CustomProperty> _props = new List<CustomProperty>();

        [Browsable(false)]
        public string ObjectName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        public List<CustomProperty> Properties
        {
            get { return _props; }
            set { _props = value; }
        }

        private readonly Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public object this[string name]
        {
            get { object val; values.TryGetValue(name, out val); return val; }
            set { values.Remove(name); }
        }

        private class CustomObjectConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter 
        {
            public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
            {
                var stdProps = base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
                var obj = value as CustomObjectType;
                var customProps = obj == null ? null : obj.Properties;
                var props = new PropertyDescriptor[stdProps.Count + (customProps == null ? 0 : customProps.Count)];
                stdProps.CopyTo(props, 0);
                if (customProps != null)
                {
                    int index = stdProps.Count;
                    foreach (CustomProperty prop in customProps)
                    {
                        props[index++] = new CustomPropertyDescriptor(prop);
                    }
                }
                return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(props);
            }

            public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
            {
                if (value is CustomObjectType)
                {
                    return (value as CustomObjectType).ObjectName;    
                }
                return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
            }
        }

        private class CustomPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
        {
            private readonly CustomProperty _prop;
            public CustomPropertyDescriptor(CustomProperty prop)
                : base(prop.Name, null)
            {
                _prop = prop;
            }                

            public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return _prop.HasDifference; } }
            public override string Category { get { return "Main Category"; } }
            public override string Description { get { return _prop.Desc; } }
            public override string Name { get { return _prop.Name; } }
            public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return ((CustomObjectType)component)[_prop.Name] != null; }
            public override void ResetValue(object component) { ((CustomObjectType)component)[_prop.Name] = null; }                
            public override Type PropertyType { get { return _prop.Type; } }
            public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return true; }
            public override Type ComponentType { get { return typeof(CustomObjectType); } }
            public override void SetValue(object component, object value) { ((CustomObjectType)component)[_prop.Name] = value; }
            public override object GetValue(object component) { return ((CustomObjectType)component)[_prop.Name] ?? _prop.DefaultValue; }
        }
    }

    public class CustomProperty
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public object DefaultValue { get; set; }
        public bool HasDifference { get; set; }

        Type _type;

        public Type Type
        {
            get
            {
                return _type;
            }
            set
            {
                _type = value;
                DefaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Highlighting property]

Hope it will help to someone.

Comment: Hi maybe dumb question but are the red properties read only now that you did that? I need to do the same thing.